# Why does VS Code give me the 'not recognized as an internal or external command' error?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, executable

I was using HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript to code a simple one page website in Visual Studio Code. I basically only added a background image and a header containing a logo and title when I left to do something else. When I came back, I recieved the following error:

> Error spawning PHP: Command failed with exit code 1: C:/Program
> Files/Ampps/php --version 'C:\Program Files\Ampps\php' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file.

This is weird considering nothing was changed on the computer during the 15 minutes between me working on the website and getting the error.

I already tried adding the PHP path to PHP Executable Path setting as follows:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast Light",
    "php.executablePath": "C:/Program Files/Ampps/php74",
    "php.executables": {},
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open"
}
```

I also added the path to the environment variables, I checked my firewall permissions, updated VS Code and made sure all my extentions are up to date while restarting my PC after each attempt at removing the error message, but so far nothing has worked.

[image: Screenshots of the latest error message and path:]

[image: Note that I tried adding both php files present in the screenshot]

Comment: Where is `.exe`?

Comment: I added it and restarted VS Code but I still get the same error @shingo

Comment: The same? Do you know which extension spawned this error?

Comment: The source is from PHP IntelliSense

Comment: Have you tried Windows path separators? `C:\\Program Files\\Ampps\\php74`?

Comment: @JoalizeMinnaar Are you sure that the error displayed after modifying the path is still the same as the one in this question? If so, you should modify the `.vscode/settings.json` in the current workspace.

Comment: I've modified the settings.json in both user and workspace and yes it is the same message the only difference is after adding the .exe the message also added the .exe

Comment: Have you confirmed the existence of the modified path?

Comment: Yes I found the .exe file first then copied and pasted the path into VS Code

Comment: This is too weird. Can you share screenshots of the latest error and the path where php.exe is located?

Comment: I added them to the original post\

Comment: @JoalizeMinnaar php74 is a folder, I think php.exe is in it, so the path should be `....php74/php.exe`